# UIPickerView custom layout with .xib files

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I am trying to create a custom UIPicker where each item is a `.xib` file instance .

I got an `Array index out of range` error with the following code:

[image]

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!)->UIView {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomItem", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check these two conditions.

- The `.xib` file needs to contain at least one view on the top level and
- The file is indeed named "customItem.xib" (and not "CustomItem" or something else).

If so, your code should work.

Comment: i added an image , rename my xib file but not not working :|

Answer (score 0):

As Mundi says what you are doing should work, but probably not well.

I predict that doing it that way is going to be too slow, and will make your picker view "stutter".

Another problem with the code you posted is that it is creating loading a new copy of a view each time the picker asks for a view. If the user scrolls through the picker view and then scrolls back the previously loaded cells will be recreated.

I would suggest pre-loading your views into an array when you first load the picker view. Then simply fetch views from the array when the picker view asks for them.

Comment: i know but the problem is about loading xib file , i can reuse loaded layout . any suggestion ?!

Comment: Break it into simpler steps and debug them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

i changed root view from `Custom View` to `View` in `.xib` file.

but drag a `View` was not supported , i copy a `.xib` file from a github sample project .